# How to properly cascade removal of an Entity from a Collection?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I am trying to get a Many-to-One relationship working smoothly between two Hibernate entities with a join table, but I am having an issue with cascading the removal of an entity from the "one" side collection.

I am omitting the simple getters/setters in the following code snippets.

## The Code

**The "one" side entity represents an FTP_SERVER in the database:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ftp_server")
public class FtpServerEntity {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "ftpServer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
  private List<SmtpRecipientEntity> smtpRecipients;

}
```

**The "many" (and owning) side entity represents an SMTP_RECIPIENT:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "smtp_recipient")
public class SmtpRecipientEntity {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinTable(
        name = "ftp_error_recipient",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "smtp_recipient_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ftp_server_id")
  )
  private FtpServerEntity ftpServer;

}
```

**And the join table simply has the following foreign keys:**

```
FOREIGN KEY (smtp_recipient_id) REFERENCES smtp_recipient (id)
FOREIGN KEY (ftp_server_id) REFERENCES ftp_server (id)
```

## The Problem

Simply adding an SmtpRecipientEntity to the FtpServerEntity#smtpRecipients Collection works fine and a row is created in the join table upon an update.

However, when I modify the collection, and then persist the FtpServerEntity, the removed records are not deleted from the join table.

I.E.

```
// This has three SmtpRecipientEntity objects in its collection
FtpServerEntity ftpServer = ftpServerDao.get(ftpServerId);

List<SmtpRecipientEntity> recipients = ftpServer.getSmtpRecipients();
recipients.clear();
recipients.add(smtpRecipientDao.get(smtpRecipientId));

// The collection now has only one different entity in it
ftpServerDao.save(ftpServer);  // performs a merge and flush
```

This code will add a new record to the join table for the entity added to the collection, but does not remove the records for the ones that are no longer in the collection. I can do this manually a couple of different ways, but this feels like something Hibernate should be able to handle.

Any ideas on what I am missing? Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `orphanRemoval = true` in addition to your `Cascade.ALL`, so that child element will be removed when it's no longer referenced from owner.